# Supersized, show a div depending on the slide

Tags: jquery, alert

**EDIT:**

So, I want to take a different approach to try and clarify what I'm looking for, I've been reading as much as I could these last hours and I feel I have a better grasp of how the system works, but I still don't know how to accomplish my goal.

**Reference links:**

[->SUPERSIZED API](http://www.dlacrem.com/slideshow/slide.html)

So, I have the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document.body).ready(function () {

        if (vars.current_slide == 5){**-I want it to display a div if the slider is the number 5-**     

}       

    });

</script>
```

My questions are these:

1) What do I add in the **- -** area to display a div that only shows up when the slider is at the 5th slide?

2) Am I doing the rest right or am I missing something? I created that code so it could be terribly wrong lol, hopefuly I got something right :P

That's all, hope this clarifies it.

Thank you all for the help! I'm really excited to start creating my own scripts :D

---

Alright, so I've uploaded the site with the code you posted and it still doesn't seem to work, I also tried reducing the code to the conditional and the result only but that didn't work either, mind checking it out?

---

### [Click Here](http://www.dlacrem.com/slideshow/slide.html)

Thanks for giving it a thought!

Comment: something like that ? so, you will have to change to the real feed object [**Click Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/corotchi/26Fzn/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you can manage to create that div using some HTML and CSS.

Now, if I understood right, your question is how you can show certain extra information in that div for certain slides.

The method for setting the contents of a div in jQuery is quite easy:

```
$("#id_of_div").html("Any <b>HTML</b> content here");
```

So if you want to set the content of the div to the value of testfield, use

```
$("#id_of_div").html(testfield);
```

#### edit in response to question edit

Unfortunately, Supersized does not provide great triggers - the only option you have is editing your theme files.

Your best option is probably to add the following code to the `theme.afterAnimation()` function; for the default theme this is located near the bottom of `slideshow/theme/supersized.shutter.js`.

```
// current slide is #5
if (vars.current_slide == 5) {
    // Get contents of the 'testfield' field
    var testfield = api.getField(testfield);
    // Set the HTML content of testfielddiv to the value of testfield
    if (testfield != "undefined") {
        $("#testfielddiv").html(testfield);

        // Show testfielddiv (which was hidden for all other slides)
        // The 'fast' argument is for a simple animation; it can be omitted
        // to show without animation, or changed to 'slow' or a number in ms
        $("#testfielddiv").show('fast');
    }
}

else {
    // Hide testfielddiv for any other slide
    $("#testfielddiv").hide('fast');
}
```

Comment: Hello Banaan, let's see if I can explain myself better here.

Each slide is defined by:{image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/shaden-3.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Brooke Shaden', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/shaden-3.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/06/brooke-shaden/'}

Then you can define new fields to add in the slide by using the function i posted on the OP, those new fields will only display on the slide, just like the different titles displays on their own slide.

Comment: So do you want to display that extra field in the same div as the title? Basically, what I gave you is how to put the value of testfield in any div. I hope it got you at least a little further...

Comment: Alright, I edited my first post to clarify it, thanks for the help mate.

Comment: Alright, so I've uploaded the site with the code you posted and it still doesn't seem to work, I also tried reducing the code to the conditional and the result only but that didn't work either, mind checking it out? www.dlacrem.com/slideshow/slide.html

Comment: I hope this fixes it... The code was not triggered for each slide.

Comment: Now that's getting much closer, the trigger is working and it shows the #testfielddiv curiously on the 6th slide (seems 0 is the first slide) and hides it in the rest. It also shows when you first load the page but I think I know how to change that. The first part of the code, the getfield isn't working though, but I almost prefer it this way so I can define the content within the divs without having to put all the code in the images area. I'm going to keep messing with it, but thank you man, you sure helped me!

Comment: Changed the css to display:none and now it only shows when the slider is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

Is simple:

1. Open the file: supersized.shutter.js
2. Find out the following line:

   ```
   slide_current: '.slidenumber', // Current slide number
   ```
3. This class ".slidenumber" contain the current number slide. Then, you can use it in your page:

   ```
   <div class="slidenumber"></div>
   ```