# add text to slide - supersized jquery

Tags: jquery, html, supersized

I'm trying to add a DIV with information to each slide from Supersized plugin.
I was searching for information and I found this [Supersized, show a div depending on the slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772295/supersized-show-a-div-depending-on-the-slide), (I asked a new question about it, because it is from the last year).

I would like to add some text to each slide, so here is my code:

```
<head>
....
    <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(function($){

            $.supersized({

                // Functionality
                slideshow               :   1,          // Slideshow on/off
                autoplay                :   0,          // Slideshow starts playing automatically
                start_slide             :   1,          // Start slide (0 is random)
                stop_loop               :   0,          // Pauses slideshow on last slide
                random                  :   0,          // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
                slide_interval          :   3000,       // Length between transitions
                transition              :   6,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                transition_speed        :   1000,       // Speed of transition
                new_window              :   1,          // Image links open in new window/tab
                pause_hover             :   1,          // Pause slideshow on hover
                keyboard_nav            :   1,          // Keyboard navigation on/off
                performance             :   1,          // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
                image_protect           :   1,          // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

                // Size & Position                         
                min_width               :   0,          // Min width allowed (in pixels)
                min_height              :   0,          // Min height allowed (in pixels)
                vertical_center         :   1,          // Vertically center background
                horizontal_center       :   1,          // Horizontally center background
                fit_always              :   0,          // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
                fit_portrait            :   1,          // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
                fit_landscape           :   0,          // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

                // Components                           
                slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
                thumb_links             :   1,          // Individual thumb links for each slide
                thumbnail_navigation    :   0,          // Thumbnail navigation
                slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
                                                    {image : 'img/1.jpg', title : '', thumb : '', url : ''},
                                                    {image : 'img/2.jpg', title : '', thumb : '', url : ''},  
                                                    {image : 'img/3.jpg', title : '', thumb : '', url : ''},
                                                    {image : 'img/4.jpg', title : '', thumb : '', url : ''},
                                                    {image : 'img/5.jpg', title : '', thumb : '', url : ''}                                                     
                                            ],

                // Theme Options               
                progress_bar            :   1,          // Timer for each slide                         
                mouse_scrub             :   0

            });
        });

    </script>


</head>


<body>
<div id="txtslide">
   Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.           
</div>
</body>
```

and in **slideshow/theme/supersized.shutter.js** I copied the example what I mention above

```
/* After Slide Transition
----------------------------*/
afterAnimation : function(){
    if (api.options.progress_bar && !vars.is_paused) theme.progressBar();   //  Start progress bar


// current slide is #3
if (vars.current_slide == 3) {
    // Get contents of the 'testfield' field
    var testfield = api.getField(testfield);
    // Set the HTML content of testfielddiv to the value of testfield
    if (testfield != "undefined") {
        $("#txtslide").html(testfield);

        // Show testfielddiv (which was hidden for all other slides)
        // The 'fast' argument is for a simple animation; it can be omitted
        // to show without animation, or changed to 'slow' or a number in ms
        $("#txtslide").show('fast');
    }
}

else {
    // Hide testfielddiv for any other slide
    $("#txtslide").hide('fast');
}
```

But this example it's not working, maybe I am doing something wrong, hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is going on in your `<head>`? There appears to be a key value pair adrift in html.

Comment: +10000 For `What is going on in your <head>?`

Comment: sorry guys, I am asking for help because I am learning and I am trying to understand. I can't add this div with text.

Comment: I tried with something like this, but it doesn't work 

{image : 'materiales/hojas/1.jpg', title : '<div style="position:absolute; float:left; margin-top:180px; width:100px; height:50px; color:#ffffff; z-index:30;">something</div>', thumb : '', url : ''},

Answer (score 1):

so I know that this is an old thread, but I wanted to do this too and found a pretty easy answer. I thought I'd post incase others come along needing the same help.

If you look at the html page that Supersized! provides, you'll notice at the bottom of the document all the divs containing the buttons for navigation, thumbnails, etc. 
One of those is labeled "Slide Captions Displayed Here"

If you just take that div and move it where you want it placed within your html document, you can just use the "title" attribute within the "slideshow images" area. The id to use in your CSS is "#slidecaption". (Probably already stylized in an included CSS document so go find it if you don't want your styles to conflict).

Also, that "title" area works with regular html tags, so use `<p>`, `<br>`, or anything else you want within there to help control the style for it.

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you are on the right way.

I have made it like this!

in the slide array

```
 {
  image : 'one.jpg',
  title : '<a href="url"><div id="slidefillimage"> <b>blablabla and blablabla</div></a>',
  thumb : 'url photo',
  url : ''
 }
```

and this in the supersized.shutter.css, i modified the slidecaption

```
#slidecaption {
    position:absolute;
    height: 80px;
    top: 300px;
    bottom:0;
    right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: 10px;
    text-align:left;
    color: #FFFFFF; 
    font: 400 14px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

and make an new entry for the new div

```
#slidefillimage {
    height: 60px;
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 900px;    
    width: expression(document.body.clientWidth < 152? "150px" : document.body.clientWidth > 902? "900px" : "auto");  
    text-indent: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #00517D; 
    font: 400 16px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

This works perfect for me!